# Anything Slider, Accordion, Vimeo, doesn't pause on sliding if video appended

Tags: vimeo, jquery-ui-accordion, anythingslider

I am using Anything Slider with Jquery UI accordion and the problem occurs when I append the slides inside accordion like this:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    change: function(event, ui) {
        var active = $("#accordion").accordion('option','active');
        switch(active){
            case 0:
                $("#slider1").append('<li class="panel1"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/18011143?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="600" height="338" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>');
                $("#slider1").append('<li class="panel2"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/12280336?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="600" height="338" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>');
                $('#slider1').anythingSlider();
                ...
```

THe thing that stops working is pause when I navigate the slides (video plays in the background when you are on the next slide)

The pausing works just fine if I write the slides in HTML like:

```
<ul id="slider1">   <!-- START AnythingSlider -->
    <li class="panel1"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/18011143?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="600" height="338" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>
    <li class="panel2"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/12280336?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="600" height="338" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>
</ul> <!-- END AnythingSlider -->
```

I hope I made it clear, any help will be most appriciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank for the info, btw after much more searching I came across ('#id').anythingSliderVideo(); and calling that after ('#id').anythingSlider(); actually works!

but I had to change the append part to:

```
$("#panel1").append('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/18011143?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="600" height="338" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
$("#panel2").append('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/12280336?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="600" height="338" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
```

and put the:

```
<li class="panel1"></li>
<li class="panel2"></li>
```

directly to html...

I don't know if this is optimal but it does the job for me.

So there it is, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Right now the video extension for AnythingSlider doesn't support dynamically adding videos to the slider. I'll look into adding this ability in the future, but I haven't had much time to rewrite that extension. Sorry =(